# My svg path gets pixelation with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm working with d3, and I'm doing some line charts. The line charts never gave me problems, until I added another svg chart and it gets pixelated only in that view.

[image]

I dont know if you note this, but that chart is strange.

When I remove the other svg in the chart I get the chart normal.

[image]

I dont know if you can see the difference.

(I know that it's not the same chart, but that's not the point)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your SVG for the [shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) property. I can image that the other chart sets it to `crispEdges` or `optimizeSpeed` for every SVG element.

This value can make sense if your chart has only rectangular shapes (like a bar chart) as it will make the bars look "sharper", but you don't want it on any "round" shapes as they will appear pixelated.

Comment: Do you know if i have to change that property on the svg, or in the particular path that is pixelated?

Comment: It worked perfectly. I had to change the attr shape-rendering on the path element.